# How to resolve ERC-20 Token transfer might have failed issue?

Tags: ether, erc-20

I withdrew ARCT (ArbitrageCT) tokens from (yobit.net) to my ether address. It was listed as successful in the exchange but the tokens were not added to my address. On checking the transaction it said; the token transfer might have failed.
Why did this fail? Was there issue in exchange or contract ?
Many other people have faced same problem.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x240146d7ea604ea6742030f209adcf906d41bdf1baf6f4815e4fc2fc1809028a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that account didn't have enough funds in it to complete that transaction when it made it. Ask the exchange to resubmit it, the transaction details prove that it wasn't processed as expected because it doesn't include the `Transfer` log.

As a side note, if you're a developer, note that the token contract your transferring funds too could potentially have security vulnerabilities since it doesn't protect against overflow. To prevent these issues they could use the [SafeMath library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol).